# How to use ioloops with multithreading in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado, pyzmq

I have problem figuring out how to use zmq with ioloops and multithreading. Whatever I'm doing I have some exceptions.

```
    __author__ = 'michael'
    class ZmqLoopRunner(Thread):

        def __init__(self, callback):
            super(ZmqLoopRunner, self).__init__()
            self.loop = IOLoop.current()
            self.callback = callback

        def run(self):
            self.loop.start()
            print('loop have been stopped')
            self.callback()

        def stop(self):
            self.loop.stop()

class BaseZmqNode():
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, host, port,  bind, hwm):
        self.node = self.create_node()
        self.node.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.context = zmq.Context().instance()
        self.socket = self.create_socket()
        if bind:
            self.socket.bind(self.build_address(host, port))
        else:
            self.socket.connect(self.build_address(host, port))
        self.set_hwm(hwm)

    def set_hwm(self, hwm):
        self.socket.set_hwm(hwm)

    def send_multipart(self, message):
        self.socket.send_multipart(message)

    def send_json(self, json):
        self.socket.send_json(json)

    def create_node(self):
        return BaseMessagingNode

    def close(self):
        self.socket.close()

    @staticmethod
    def build_address(host, port):
        strings = [host, ':', str(port)]
        return ''.join(strings)

    @abstractmethod
    def create_socket(self):
        pass

class BaseZmqReceiver(BaseZmqNode):

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, host, port, hwm, bind, on_receive_callback):
        super(BaseZmqReceiver, self).__init__(host=host, port=port, bind=bind, hwm=hwm)
        self.node.on_message_callback = on_receive_callback
        self.stream = ZMQStream(self.socket)
        self.stream.on_recv(self.on_message_received)
        self.runner = ZmqLoopRunner(self.stream.close)
        self.runner.start()

    def on_message_received(self, message):
        return self.node.on_message_callback(message)

    def create_node(self):
        return ReceivingNode(None, None)


    def close(self):
        # super(BaseZmqReceiver, self).close()

        self.runner.stop()

        # self.socket.close()
```

Here is how my code looks right now. I have exceptions in test 'Address already in use' when running my tests.

Here is stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/leos/code/messaging_system/tests/ZmqTest.py", line 51, in test_send_json
    publisher = ZmqPublisher('tcp://*', 6000)
  File "/opt/leos/code/messaging_system/zeromq/ZmqPublisher.py", line 11, in __init__
    super(ZmqPublisher, self).__init__(host=host, port=port, bind=bind, hwm=hwm)
  File "/opt/leos/code/messaging_system/zeromq/BaseZmqNode.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.socket.bind(self.build_address(host, port))
  File "socket.pyx", line 434, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:3928)
  File "checkrc.pxd", line 21, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:6058)
ZMQError: Address already in use

class ZmqTest(AbstractMessagingTest):

    def setUp(self):
        super(ZmqTest, self).setUp()
        self.multipart_messages = self.create_multipart_messages(10)

    def tearDown(self):
        super(ZmqTest, self).tearDown()

    def test_request_reply(self):
        requester = ZmqReq(host='tcp://localhost', port=6000)
        self.request = 'Hello'
        self.reply = 'World!'
        replier = ZmqRep(host='tcp://*', port=6000, request_processor=self.on_request_received)
        self.assertEqual(self.reply, requester.execute(request=self.request))
        # requester.close()
        replier.close()
        requester.close()

    def test_address_creation(self):
        full_address = "tcp://localhost:5559"
        self.assertEqual(full_address, ZmqSubscriber.build_address("tcp://localhost", 5559))
        self.assertEqual('tcp://*:6000', ZmqPublisher.build_address("tcp://*", 6000))

    def test_publisher_subscriber(self):

        publisher = ZmqPublisher('tcp://*', 6000)
        subscriber = ZmqSubscriber('tcp://localhost', 6000, self.handle_message)
        self.send_messages(publisher, wait=False)
        sleep(0.5)
        self.assertSequenceEqual(self.test_messages, self.received_messages)
        publisher.close()
        subscriber.close()

    def handle_message(self, message):
        self.base_handle_message(message[0])

    def test_send_json(self):
        publisher = ZmqPublisher('tcp://*', 6000)
        subscriber = ZmqSubscriber('tcp://localhost', 6000, self.handle_json_message)
        md = {'1' : 1}
        publisher.send_json(md)
        publisher.close()
        subscriber.close()

    def create_multipart_messages(self, size):
        messages = []
        for i in range(size):
            messages.append(['Multipart test message', str(i)])
        return messages

    def send_multipart_messages(self, sender):
        for message in self.multipart_messages:
            sender.send_multipart(message)


    def test_multipart_messages(self):
        publisher = ZmqPublisher('tcp://*', 6000)
        subscriber = ZmqSubscriber('tcp://localhost', 6000, self.base_handle_message)
        self.send_multipart_messages(publisher)
        sleep(0.5)
        self.assertSequenceEqual(self.multipart_messages, self.received_messages)
        publisher.close()
        subscriber.close()

    def test_push_pull_multipart(self):
        ventilator = ZmqPush('tcp://*', 6000)
        worker = ZmqPull('tcp://localhost', 6000, self.base_handle_message)
        self.send_multipart_messages(ventilator)
        sleep(0.5)
        self.assertSequenceEqual(self.multipart_messages, self.received_messages)
        ventilator.close()
        worker.close()


    def handle_json_message(self, json):
        print(str(json))

    def test_push_pull(self):
        ventilator = ZmqPush('tcp://*', 6000)
        worker = ZmqPull('tcp://localhost', 6000, self.handle_message)
        self.send_messages(ventilator, wait=False)
        sleep(0.5)
        self.assertSequenceEqual(self.test_messages, self.received_messages)
        ventilator.close()
        worker.close()

    def on_request_received(self, message):
        if message[0] == self.request:
            return self.reply
        else:
            return 'ERROR'
```

And I've tried many variants of this code. Like as you can see right now I'm trying to close the stream after the loop.start() method returned. I've tried to close the stream after the stop method and it just don't work.

Comment: You're not really asking a question here. You asking someone to take your code, run it and try to figure out what exceptions are thrown. You haven't even explained where or what exceptions are thrown. Could you elaborate about the problem in the question? Ideally a stack trace of the exceptions you are seeing would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added stacktrace. But I don't think it would help you. I think that my problem is that I'm doing something completely wrong here, but I don't know what. So my question is not about what's wrong in my code probably, but more about how to do the task that I want in right way.

Answer (score 1):

So you're getting the error that the socket address is already open. This is probably because you have run up the program, an exception was thrown and you haven't closed down the socket.

I'd suggest some `try`, `except` and `finally` blocks:

```
try:
    requester = ZmqReq(host='tcp://localhost', port=6000)
    self.request = 'Hello'
    self.reply = 'World!'
    replier = ZmqRep(host='tcp://*', port=6000, request_processor=self.on_request_received)
    self.assertEqual(self.reply, requester.execute(request=self.request))
except Exception as e:
    # You can catch exceptions here
    pass
finally:
    # Once the code completes or exceptions are thrown, clean up
    replier.close()
    requester.close()
```

Comment: Looks like you're gonna have to start debugging!

Comment: I don't think that this would help me unless I would understand all of the code of the pyzmq. Because it's where the problem is I think. Also this is most probably concurrency issue, which is almost impossible to debug in debugger.

Comment: Everything can be solved with good old fashioned problem isolation and solving. Narrow down the problem until you find it. Good luck!